# What would be a good accompaniment for Ostrich fillet with Port and Blue Cheese glaze?

Tags: pairing, menu-planning, serving-suggestion

On the heel of @ElendilThetall's question: [Accompiniments for satay](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/what-are-some-appropriate-accompaniments-for-satay), I'd like to know the following.

About a year ago I found this great recipe for [Ostrich Fillet](http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/ostrich-with-port-blue-cheese-glaze-10000000523275/), which is basically flash fried in the pan and then the leftover juices is cooked along with port and blue cheese to create a great-tasting glaze.

I haven't had the chance to make this very often, but it's an amazingly tasty, quick and easy thing to make. The problem I have is figuring out what would go well with this.

At the moment my favourite is a baked potato and roast vegetables, however I'm not so good with the roast veggies. I've also worked under the assumption that anything that goes with regular red meat, like chips, works well, but this is such a unique tasting dish that I'd really like to do something different along with it.

Unfortunately I don't really have a knack for pairing side-dishes with recipes like these, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had french fries with (beef) gravy and blue cheese, and it's delicious. However, if you want to get away from potatoes and aren't comfortable with roasting, what about doing some other sort of root vegetable mash? Like mash potatoes, but using turnips, parsnips, rutabaga, or sweet potato instead. I've tried them all and I think they're great.

As for a side veg, I'd almost want a really vinegary salad. Something astringent to cut the richness of the dish. To carry the theme, you may like a green salad with apples, walnuts, and a little blue cheese, with a vinegary italian dressing. I imagine that any kind of pickled veg would be nice, too.

Comment: Hmmm, some really delicious sounding idea. I especially like your vinegary salad one. It's not so much that I want to get away from potatoes, it's more just I don't want to do the standard steak and chips type of thing. But the other mashed roots also sounds really interesting. I will have to give it a try. The apples, walnuts and blue cheese salad also sounds very tasty.

Answer (score 1):

Potatoes are a good choice - perhaps some roasted or parmentier-style, or even fondant potatoes. And a bit of greenery - simple wilted spinach or steamed green beans.

Comment: Hmmm, somehow I've overlooked spinach. Think that would go nicely. Nice suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A mushrooom sauce over the ostrich steak / fillet, with either mashed potatoes, steamed green beans with pepper and butter or steamed mixed vegetables go really nice together.  Mushroom sauce I sautee the onion and mushrooms for about 3 to 4  min, add garlic, fresh cream with a bit of milk and I also add a bit of cake wheat flour to thicken the sauce a bit

Comment: Petra, welcome to the site! I see your effort and actually this suggestion is not a bad one (although opinions may differ on blue cheese and mushrooms). Unfortunately recipe recommendations are off-topic for a good reason - there simply is no "correct" answer -  and [off-topic questions shouldn't be answered](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Of course you couldn't know this and frankly, this question should have been closed years ago but must have slipped notice.